# Create JS array with dynamic values

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Currently I create an array like this:

```
[c%256,2*c%256,3*c%256,4*c%256]
```

I have to multiply the variable `c` with the current position in array + 1 and then modulo 256.

Is there a better / smaller way to do that. Something with ES6?

Say I want that with an array length of 20?

Comment: Thought about that. But no, I first have to calculate c*n and then %256

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const createArray = (length, c) => {
  return [...Array(length).keys()].map(i => (i + 1) * c % 256)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and generate an array with the wanted length and map the wanted values.

```js
function getArray(length, c) {
    var f = c % 256;
    return Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => f * (i + 1));
}

console.log(getArray(5, 266));
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses ES6 map.  It avoids a loop or array declaration.  The array is allocated with the correct size from the start (no pushing/resizing).

```js
//[c%256,2*c%256,3*c%256,4*c%256]

const c = 12
const count = 100

const items = Array(count).fill().map((_, i) => ((i + 1) * c) % 256)

console.log(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```js
const c = 32;

const result = Array(20).fill().map((x,i) => (c * i+1) % 256);

console.dir(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var c = 5;
var arr = Array.apply(null, Array(20))
var output = arr.map( (v,i) => (c*(i+1)%256) )
console.log(output)

// single line
var c = 8
console.log(Array.apply(null, Array(20)).map( (v,i) => (c*(i+1)%256) ))
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this without ES6:

```
function createArray(variable, length) {
    var arr = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        arr.push((i+1) * variable % 256);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: You _can_ do it without es6, but the question does ask for something better/smaller

Comment: something better/smaller than what? The question is not clear on that and does not give an example. The way the question is worded suggests, that the person asking is not aware of how to do it in general.

Comment: I think I interpreted the question differently; the user already has _a_ way of generating the array, they ask "Is there a better / smaller way to do that. Something with ES6?"

Comment: Then he should have posted his code that should be optimized

Comment: The code was provided: `[c%256,2*c%256,3*c%256,4*c%256]`

Comment: Yes, and the question was `Is there a better / smaller way to do that. Something with ES6?.` This does not say that the solution has to neccessarily use ES6. I answered the question whether there is a better way to do it and said that he does not need ES6 for it.